# Navigation drawer icon, ripple effect like Photos app

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm on Lollipop (minSdk=21) and using the v7-appcompat ActionBarDrawerToggle together with the Toolbar, like this (onCreate()):

```
    setActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.action_open_drawer, R.string.action_close_drawer);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
```

I also have the syncState() call in onPostCreate() etc. Generally, it all works well, and the hamburger-to-arrow spinning animation works fine.

I noticed, though, that the icon is 'square' and the press animation ripple is restricted to it. However, certain other apps, like the Android photos app, have the hamburger-to-arrow icons not restricted, i.e. the ripple effect goes outside the actual square area reserved for the icon.

How can I achieve something similar in my app?